# Make new sheet from column value using format from template sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I am trying to create a new sheet for each item listed in column A of the master sheet and then have those new sheets use the template I created on a separate sheet (both in the same file).

So far I have the following, but they are not working together and it is not automated:

```
function makeSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets[0].getRange('A2:A100')
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (el, i) {
        if (el[0] && !ss.getSheetByName(el[0])) ss.insertSheet(el[0], sheets.length +i)
    });
}
```

AND

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var name = "labnol";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template').copyTo(ss);

  /* Before cloning the sheet, delete any previous copy */
  var old = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old); // or old.setName(new Name);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Utilities.sleep(2000);
  sheet.setName(company);

  /* Make the new sheet active */
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed `insertSheet` documentation?

Comment: No, I did get an error back, but not sure how to correct as I am not a coder...these are scripts that i found through research

Comment: @tehhowch updated. thanks.

Comment: @TreneishaPatton what's the error message? Sorry, I should have mentioned that you want to include the error text.

Comment: @tehhowch actually when I just ran it again there was no error. My main thing is merging these two to work together and creating a trigger so that it performs automatically

Comment: @TreneishaPatton manually create a trigger for a function that calls these as needed. You only need programmatic trigger creation in very select situations, usually always add-ons.